# Using Xamarin ValueConverter manually to test by unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write unit tests for my `ValueConverter`s. So I need to call them manually.

Something like:

```cs
var converter = new IntToBoolConverter();
Assert.AreEqual(true, converter.Convert(1));
Assert.AreEqual(true, converter.Convert(12));
Assert.AreEqual(false, converter.Convert(0));
```

But I haven't found any way to use converter manually like calling `converter.Convert(12)`.
How can I use converters manually so I can write unit tests for it?

Comment: Why can't you just call its [`Convert` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.ivalueconverter.convert?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_IValueConverter_Convert_System_Object_System_Type_System_Object_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_)?

Comment: @canton7 You're right. My mistake... I'm using a library that made this method `protected` so I haven't access to it anymore. I should communicate with them. As a workaround, for now, I've manually cast it to `IValueConverter` and worked.

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at the library and seeing what method(s) it provides in its place?